# How to use multiple word in "startsWith"

Tags: javascript

```
if (message.content.startsWith('let', 'Let')){/do something/})
```

I want bot work when user type "let" or "Let", but it can just work when "let" typed
How to fix this?
Thanks for helping

Comment: `if(message.content.startsWith('let') || message.content.startsWith('Let'))`

Comment: According to [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith), the `String.prototype.startsWith` function can only take one search string as input. If you need to search across multiple lines, you can use the `||` operator, or use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use regex for this. They perform better, are powerful and flexible, and could be more readable. To achieve your goal in this case, simply match for the beginning of the string (`with ^`). Something like:

```js
if (/^(L|l)et/.test(message.content)) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: This helps me a lot, I can use in another code ,thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions here:

```js
var terms = ["let", "Let"];
var regex = new RegExp("^(?:" + terms.join("|") + ")\\b");
var inputs = ["Let it be!", "let it be!", "Green Eggs and Ham"];
for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    if (regex.test(inputs[i])) {
        console.log("MATCH    => " + inputs[i]);
    }
    else {
        console.log("NO MATCH => " + inputs[i]);
    }
}
```

To be clear, we are using `test()` with the regex pattern:

```regex
^(?:let|Let)\b
```

You may add more terms to the above alternation as needed.

Answer (score 0):

To keep things flexible you could keep an array of words you want to check, and then use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check to see if any of those words are at the beginning of the content string.

```js
const words = ['let', 'Let', 'Bob'];

const message1 = { content: 'let' };
const message2 = { content: 'notlet' };
const message3 = { content: 'Let' };
const message4 = { content: 'Bob' };

function startsWith(message) {
  return words.some(word => {
    return message.content.startsWith(word);
  });
}

console.log(startsWith(message1));
console.log(startsWith(message2));
console.log(startsWith(message3));
console.log(startsWith(message4));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for case insensitive match. In that case following can work assuming your `message.content` is a string or object.
Here we collect user typed string in `userTypedThis` variable.

```
if (message.content.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(
   userTypedThis.toString().toLowerCase())
){/do something/})
```